# Cannot resolve method 'resolvePythonScriptPath'

Tags: java, integration, processbuilder

I'm following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-working-with-python) tutorial about integrating `Java` and `Python`.

And I keep getting `Cannot resolve method 'resolvePythonScriptPath' in 'TestIntegration'`
what import am I missing for this method `resolvePythonScriptPath()` ?

This is my code:

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.SimpleScriptContext;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TestIntegration {
    @Test
    public void givenPythonScriptEngineIsAvailable_whenScriptInvoked_thenOutputDisplayed() throws Exception {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();
        context.setWriter(writer);

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
        engine.eval(new FileReader(resolvePythonScriptPath("hello.py")), context);
        assertEquals("Should contain script output: ", "Hello Baeldung Readers!!", writer.toString().trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: The method doesn't come from an import, you should write it yourself. I suggest you take another look at the file you copied the code from (the github linked at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your own method. it could be something like:

```java
private String resolvePythonScriptPath(String path){
   File file = new File(path);
   return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```